# Failed to run selenium with googlechrome

Tags: selenium

1.start the selenium server:

```
sudo java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -port 4444 <br>
........
09:02:06.523 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x <br>
09:02:06.526 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver] <br>
09:02:06.533 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]<br>
09:02:06.537 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]<br>
09:02:06.571 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@7df17e77<br>
09:02:06.571 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]<br>
09:02:06.574 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444<br>
09:02:06.577 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@798fd984<br>
```

2.run test case in perl:

```
my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", <br>
                                port => 4444, <br>
                                browser => "*googlechrome", <br>
                                browser_url => "http://>fns-IP/" );<br>

$sel->start;
$sel->open_ok("http://>fns-IP/login");
```

3.test log:

```
09:09:25.146 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*googlechrome, http://>fns-IP/] on session null<br>
09:09:25.146 INFO - creating new remote session<br>
09:09:25.147 INFO - Allocated session 553a1b30a1dd4f8a889fa4dfb7a6ae8a for http://>fns-IP/, launching...<br>
09:09:25.147 INFO - Launching Google Chrome...<br>
09:09:30.336 INFO - Got result: OK,553a1b30a1dd4f8a889fa4dfb7a6ae8a on session 553a1b30a1dd4f8a889fa4dfb7a6ae8a<br>
09:09:30.340 INFO - Command request: open[http://>fns-IP/login, ] on session 553a1b30a1dd4f8a889fa4dfb7a6ae8a<br>
09:09:30.610 INFO - Got result: OK on session 553a1b30a1dd4f8a889fa4dfb7a6ae8a<br>
09:09:30.623 INFO - Command request: isElementPresent[id=id_username, ] on session 553a1b30a1dd4f8a889fa4dfb7a6ae8a<br>
09:09:32.393 INFO - Couldn't proxy to http://>qlriakmdkm/ because host not found<br>
09:09:32.395 INFO - Couldn't proxy to http://>wkdujqsymi/ because host not found<br>
09:09:32.393 INFO - Couldn't proxy to http://>rkjzjvpsbx/ because host not found<br>
```

4.The URL In the googlechrome browser:

```
http://>fns-IP/selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=324f251e0de64cfeafa157de0c33ed41&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ffns-4%2F&debugMode=false
```

and

```
http://>fns-IP/selenium-server/core/Blank.html?start=true
```

5.I tried on website 'ca.msn.com' and it worked well.

Any feedback is appreciated.

In all the urls quoted in 'http', the character '>' is added for a blockquote. Otherwise, it did not allow me to post. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too have faced this problem earlier but in my case trustAllSSLCertificates was suffice.
I suggest you too move to selenium webdriver that has a good support to google chrome.

Comment: Abhi,thank you for your feedback. However, all my cases are written in Selenium RC:(.